# Render last element of nested array of Object in Angular HTML template

Tags: arrays, angular

I have an Object named comment, which has description property and editedDescription Array. Whenever user edits description, new description will be pushed into editedDescription array.This array is used so as to maintain history of edited descriptions.
Following is my comment Object :

```
export interface Comment {
    userName: String,
    userImage: String,
    description: String,
    upvote : Number,
    downvote : Number,
    createdDate: Date,
    replies: [
        {
            userName: String,
            userImage: String,
            description: String,
            upvote : Number,
            downvote : Number,
            createdDate: Date
        }
    ],
    editedDescription: [
        {
            Description: String,
            editedDate: Date
        }
    ]
}
```

In order to output last element of editedDescription array, I have tried :

```
{{ comment?.editedDescription[editedDescription?.length-1]?.Description}}
```

I am getting following error - 'Cannot read property '-1' of undefined '
I have made use of safe navigation operator to check if array exists but im getting cannot read -1 of undefined

this is my code where in  part is failing

```
<div *ngIf="comment?.editedDescription?.length == 0 ; else edited_comment">
            <p> {{ comment?.description }}</p>
</div>

<ng-template #edited_comment>
          <p> {{ comment?.editedDescription[editedDescription?.length-1]?.Description}}</p>
</ng-template>
```

*ngIf conditions check if there is no data in editedDescription array, use description property else use last element of editedDescription array.

Answer (score 1):

I think it needs to be the following, as at the moment you are not trying to access the array through `comment` where it sounds like it is stored.

```
{{ comment?.editedDescription[comment.editedDescription.length -1 ]?.Description}}
```

You still need to access comment when looking for the length. Put the safety operators back in when you are happy it is working. Below shows a simplified example of what you have tried.

```js
const obj = { hello: [1, 2, 3] };

console.log(obj.hello[obj.hello.length - 1]); // last element, expected 3

// console.log(obj.hello[hello.length - 1]) // This is like what you have done.
```

Comment: Hey @dince12, the code snippet you shared does not work. Im getting ``` Cannot read property 'length' of undefined  ``` error . So i added safety operator and code became ``` comment?.editedDescription[comment?.editedDescription?.length -1 ]?.Description ``` but Im still getting same error ``` Cannot read property '-1' of undefined ```

Comment: Can you add the code of what comment looks like :-)

Comment: I have added the comment Object for reference